# Javascript for hiding dropdown list choices on pageload if first value is on default on another list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very noob and I know that my javascript code is heavy and not the most beautiful, but I am learning on a course online, so if you can offer a solution that enhances my logic or is based off of similar logic that would really help.

I am working on a project and have these two dropdown lists in html -

```
<div>
    <label for="design">Design:</label>
    <select id="design" name="user_design">
        <option>Select Theme</option>
        <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
        <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
    <label for="color">Color:</label>
    <select id="color">
        <option value="cornflowerblue">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
        <option value="darkslategrey">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="gold">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="tomato">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
        <option value="steelblue">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="dimgrey">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
    </select>
</div>
```

When the page loads the Design is on the "Select Theme" option, and the colors need to not populate on the second list until theme - JS puns is selected or Theme I <3 Js.

I already have only certain colors showing based off which design is selected, but cannot figure out how to make it where the colors list does not populate until one of the designs is selected, I tried  making it where if tShirts.value === "" (was empty, because the select a shirt has no value), then display none on all of the elements grabbed into the tShirts variable.  Any easy fixes here?

```
var tShirts = document.getElementById("design");

//get the color option values into a variable
var ShirtColors = document.getElementById("color");

//function for the value of the design selection to change the corresponding color selector menu.
tShirts.onchange = function() {
    if (tShirts.value == "js puns") {
        ShirtColors.selectedIndex = 0;
        ShirtColors[3].style.display = "none";
        ShirtColors[4].style.display = "none";
        ShirtColors[5].style.display = "none";
        ShirtColors[0].style.display = "initial";
        ShirtColors[1].style.display = "initial";
        ShirtColors[2].style.display = "initial";
    } else if (tShirts.value == "heart js") {
        ShirtColors.selectedIndex = 3;
        ShirtColors[3].style.display = "initial";
        ShirtColors[4].style.display = "initial";
        ShirtColors[5].style.display = "initial";
        ShirtColors[0].style.display = "none";
        ShirtColors[1].style.display = "none";
        ShirtColors[2].style.display = "none";
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JSON for data and play around it as:-

```
var tShirts = document.getElementById("design");
//get the color option values into a variable
var ShirtColors = document.getElementById("color");
var data = {
        "jspuns":["Cornflower Blue:value1","Dark Slate Grey:value2","Gold:value3"], // Give each one a value
"heartjs":["Tomato:value4","Steelblue:value5","dimgrey:value6"] // Give each one a value
};
//function for the value of the design selection to change the corresponding   color selector menu.
tShirts.onchange = function() {
ShirtColors.innerHTML = "";
var selectedValue = tShirts.value.split(' ').join('');
if(!data[selectedValue])
    return;
for(var i=0;i<data[selectedValue].length;i++){
    var option = document.createElement('option');
option.value= data[selectedValue][i].split(':')[1]; // After : is actual value
option.innerHTML = data[selectedValue][i].split(':')[0]; // Before : is display text
    ShirtColors.appendChild(option);
    }  
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Definitely a good way to go but his values and display text are not the same :). Perhaps another array with values sharing same index? (or expanding JSON to hold both display text and value)

Comment: @sabith I like this choice, and added an onload function to have the shirtcolors inner html be ' ' on pageload, but after selecting a theme, when I move it back to "select design" it does not remove the list again, until you try choosing a color again.  i tried using  if(Shirtdata[selectedValue][i].indexOf('Select') >= 0) {
  ShirtColors.innerHTML = "";
 } but that said indexOf function was undefined, I think I will still pass the project, since most people would not be switching back to the select design selection, but the perfectionist in me wants to find this out as well lol.  Thank you

Comment: @sabith scratch that I just read that the color selection has to read "please select a theme" until a theme is selected, I will work with changing the inner html to this

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

Add a value to "Select Theme" and an option "select design" to the colors list and play with it :)

```
 <select id="design" name="user_design">
        <option value="none">Select Theme</option> // Add a value to 'no design'
        <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
        <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
      </select>



 <div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
      <label for="color">Color:</label>
      <select id="color">       
        <option value="cornflowerblue" style="display:none">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
        <option value="darkslategrey" style="display:none">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="gold" style="display:none">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="tomato" style="display:none">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
        <option value="steelblue" style="display:none">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="dimgrey" style="display:none">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
        <option value="none" >Select Design first</option> // Tell them to select design. This is the only one showing initialy
      </select>
    </div>    


tShirts.onchange = function() {
if (tShirts.value == "none") { // Only show them select design
    ShirtColors.selectedIndex = 6;
    ShirtColors[3].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[4].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[5].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[0].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[1].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[2].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[6].style.display = "block";
} else  if (tShirts.value == "js puns") {
    ShirtColors.selectedIndex = 0;
    ShirtColors[3].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[4].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[5].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[0].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[1].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[2].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[6].style.display = "none";
} else if (tShirts.value == "heart js") {
    ShirtColors.selectedIndex = 3;
    ShirtColors[3].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[4].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[5].style.display = "block";
    ShirtColors[0].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[1].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[2].style.display = "none";
    ShirtColors[6].style.display = "none";
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must create a style as

```
// css sheet
.notInChoice { display: none }
```

create a set of arrays to arrange your data by ids

```
choices = ['choice1', ... 'choiceN'];
```

for each choice set an array to know what to show

```
choice1 = ['toshow1-1',...,'toshow1-M'];
//...
```

asign to classes to fast encode

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="choice" id="choiceI">item in your first dropdown</li>
  //...
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="underchoice" id='toshowI-j'>item in your second dropdown</li>
  // ...
</ul>
```

Now a small jQuery tip

```
function setSecondDropDown(selectedItem){
   // everybody hidden
   $('.underchoice').addClass('notInChoice');
   // you need to set the data object from your arrays
   // a small loop to show wath you need
   for (x in data[selectedItem] ){
     $('#'+x).removeClass('notInChoice');
   }
}
// binding behaviors
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.choice').click(function( event ) {
    id=$(this).attr('id');
    setSecondDropDown(id);
  });
});
```